# Why does foreign key constraint give error on insert?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How would I insert a column in this table? any help would be great. I want to be able to insert a column into the table `productview`.

I get this error when inserting even  through APEX object browser. However I am trying to do it through SQL command

```
error ORA-02291: integrity constraint (GCU.CUSVIS3ID3_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

I know the constraint name may be different here as I have many versions; it may differ sorry for that.

```
CREATE TABLE  CUSTOMERS
   ( CUSTOMERID VARCHAR2(10000) NOT NULL, 
     NAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL, 
     EMAIL VARCHAR2(50), 
     CUSTOMERTYPE VARCHAR2(23) DEFAULT  'BRONZE',
     PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMERID),
CONSTRAINT CHECK_CUSTOMERTYPE CHECK(CUSTOMERTYPE IN ('SILVER', 'GOLD'))
   );
/
CREATE TABLE  CUSTOMERVisit
   ( CUSTOMERVISITID VARCHAR2 NOT NULL, 
     VisitDatetime TIMESTAMP, 
     VisitLength NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
     PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMERVISITID),
CONSTRAINT "COUNTR_REG23324_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("CUSTOMERVISITID")
      REFERENCES  "CUSTOMERS" ("CUSTOMERID")
);

/
CREATE TABLE  PRODUCTVIEW
   ( ADDEDTOBASKET VARCHAR2,     
CONSTRAINT CHECK_ADDEDTOBASKET1 CHECK(ADDEDTOBASKET IN ('Y')),

CONSTRAINT "CUSID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ADDEDTOBASKET")
      REFERENCES  "CUSTOMERS" ("CUSTOMERID"),
CONSTRAINT "CUSVISID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ADDEDTOBASKET")
      REFERENCES  "CUSTOMERVISIT" ("CUSTOMERVISITID")

   );
```

Comment: That error means you need to have a row in the parent table for the referenced fields in your child table. Therefore, in order to insert into the child table, you must first insert a row into the parent table (assuming no row is already present).

Comment: I mean you need to have two insert statements, e.g. `insert into parent_table (col1, col2, col3, ...) values (val1, val2, val3, ....);` and `insert into child_table (cola, colb, colc, ...) values (vala, valb, valc, ...);`

Comment: Looks like maybe you're missing a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of your first insert statement. Or maybe it's an artefact of which GUI you're using to run your insert statements - some need to run multiple statements as a script (e.g. Toad, SQL Developer).

Comment: What program are you using to run your insert statements?

Comment: You have edited this question to remove a lot of the information which was needed to explain your problem. In that state the question too unclear to be answerable so I have rolled back those edits. You have also revoke your acceptance of my answer without explaining why. You should not waste the time of other people who have tried to help you. Poor show.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign keys you have posted ...

```
CONSTRAINT "CUSID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ADDEDTOBASKET")
  REFERENCES  "CUSTOMERS" ("CUSTOMERID"),
CONSTRAINT "CUSVISID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ADDEDTOBASKET")
  REFERENCES  "CUSTOMERVISIT" ("CUSTOMERVISITID")
```

... enforce links between the `PRODUCTVIEW` table and the `CUSTOMERS` and `CUSTOMERVISIT` tables. What the above code means is that the value of  `PRODUCTVIEW.ADDEDTOBASKET` must exist in `CUSTOMERVISIT.CUSTOMERVISITID` **and** must exist in `CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID` before the `PRODUCTVIEW` record can be inserted.

Clearly this is wrong, for two reasons:

- from a modelling point of view it enforces a one-to-one relationship between the three tables, which is unusual
- the datatypes are different.

It is more likely that you need a model in which one Customer can have many Customer Visits, and one Customer Visit can have multiple views. In which case:

1. `alter table customervisit drop constraint COUNTR_REG23324_FK;`
2. `alter table productview drop constraint CUSID_FK;`
3. `alter table productview drop constraint CUSVISID_FK;`
4. `alter table customervisit add customerid varchar2(10000)`;
5. `alter table customervisit add constraint customervisit_customer_fk ( customerid) references customer (customerid)`;
6. `alter table productview add customervisitid varchar2(40)`;
7. `alter table productview add constraint productview_customervisit_fk ( customerid ) references customervisit (customervisitid)`;

Incidentally, `varchar2(10000)` is quite the worst definition of a primary key I have ever seen. You should get some sort of prize for that.

Anyway, now when you insert a record you start with `CUSTOMER`. To populate `CUSTOMERVISIT` you need to pass the correct value of `CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID` to `CUSTOMERVISIT.CUSTOMERID`. Likewise to populate `PRODUCTVIEW` you need to pass the correct value of `CUSTOMERVISIT.CUSTOMERVISITID` to `PRODUCTVIEW.CUSTOMERVISITID`.

Something like this. For each new Customer:

```
insert into customers3 (customerid, NAME, email, customertype)
 values (55, 'asdsa', 'asda@gmail.com', 'GOLD');
```

For each Customer Visit:

```
insert into customervisit3 (customervisitid, customerid, 
     VisitDatetime )
  values (123 , 55, systimestamp);
```

For each Product Viewed:

```
insert into productview3 (customervisitid, addedtobasket )
  values (123 , 'Y');
```

If you're using triggers to populate IDs with a sequence value you could use the RETURNING clause to capture sequence values in a local variable.

Comment: Any particular reason you unaccepted this answer? What more do you need to know?